# Postgress time series storage from an arbitrary number of people

Tags: postgresql, database-design, schema, relational-database

I'm trying to think up a schema for storing time series data for an arbitrary number of people. Suppose I receive packets of data labeled with a UUID every few seconds. So I might receive these packets in this order

```
UUID   Time                                  Val
0Ac4x: [0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06], [0,1,10,2,3,6]
BB778: [0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06], [20,21,22,23,24,77]
0Ac4x: [0.07, 0.08], [1,2]
```

The most brain dead solution would to be to make a table with `UUID` and `Time` as a super key, and `Val` as an attribute.

```
UUID  Time  Val
0Ac4x 0.01 0
0Ac4x 0.02 1
0Ac4x 0.03 10
0Ac4x 0.04 2
0Ac4x 0.05 3
0Ac4x 0.06 6
BB778 0.01 20
...
```

then I can just query based on filtering the UUID. That seems like a horrible solution though; it messes with the continuity of the time series data and seems disorganized.

What should I include in my schema for this use case? (sorry if this is basic, I'm new to RDS)

Comment: The order in which rows are inserted into a table _has no significance!_ Your schema is fine, though of course there are other approaches that could be fine as well. How you're planning on using this data is an important piece of information to know when planning how the schema is structured.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Storage doesn't have an order and that means you can not store data in a certain order.